# How to create Index using Java API for orientdb 3.0?

Tags: java, orientdb, graph-databases

I am using oriendb [multi-model java api](http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/java/ref/). I use the [OVertex](http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/java/ref/OVertex.html) and [OEdge](http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/java/ref/OEdge.html) class to store my documents. They inherit from the [OElement](http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/java/ref/OElement.html) class. It seems that the `OElement` class does not seem to expose a `createIndex()` method. I know that this is possible if we were using the [OClass](http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/java/ref/OClass.html) to create classes and hold documents.

How do I create an index using the multi-model API if I am using the `OVertex` and `OEdge` classes.

I am missing the link `[OVertex,OEdge]--inherits-from-->[OElement]--(?)-->[OClass]`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the JAVA multi model API the cleanest way I found was:

```
// create the connection pool for orientdb
OrientDB orient = new OrientDB(orientUrl, OrientDBConfig.defaultConfig());
OrientDBConfigBuilder poolCfg = OrientDBConfig.builder();
poolCfg.addConfig(OGlobalConfiguration.DB_POOL_MIN, 2);
poolCfg.addConfig(OGlobalConfiguration.DB_POOL_MAX, 5);
ODatabasePool pool = new ODatabasePool(orientUrl, databaseName, orientUser, orientPass, poolCfg.build());

// acquire the orient pool connection
try (ODatabaseSession db = pool.acquire()) {
        // check and create vertex/edge class
        if (db.getClass("className") == null) {
            // create the class if it does not exist in the DB
            OClass orientClass =
                    db.createVertexClass("className");
            // OR db.createEdgeClass("className");
            orientClass.createProperty("id", OType.STRING);
            orientClass.createIndex("id", OClass.INDEX_TYPE.UNIQUE, "id");
        }
       // now create the OVertex/OEdge/OElement
       OVertex vertex = db.newVertex("className");
       // add properties to your document
       vertex.setProperty("id", id);
       ...
// release the connection back to the pool
} finally {
        orient.close();
    }
```

I did not find this in the document yet, so maybe it helps someone.